# In Doctrine Query Builder, how to achieve order by = a column name of a entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to sort the columns according to a column's value.

```
    $vtpQb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
                $vtpQb
                ->from("AppBundle:TrPlace","trplace")
                ->select($view_fectch_fields)
                ->join('AppBundle:TrVwPlacePrivateMarkers', 'vwpm','WITH','trplace.id = vwpm.placeId')
                ->where('vwpm.userid = :userid')
                ->setParameter("userid",$userid)
                ->orderBy('vwpm.tagStatusValue', 'DESC');
                //->orderBy('vwpm.tagStatusValue = 3', 'DESC'); got errorvwpm.tagStatusValue
```

Above is my query and I need to sort it 'vwpm.tagStatusValue = 3', How will I achieve it in Doctrine Query Builder.....

Comment: @DonCallisto Of course it is possible in SQL. `'vwpm.tagStatusValue = 3` if equal to `true` or `false`, which is converted to `1` or `0`. Such sort (with DESC direction) means that rows matching this condition will be first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing is that you cannot put expression in `orderBy` in DQL, but you can use calculated column.

Also there's no MySQL's `IF`, but there's `CASE WHEN`

This works for me. I've added `addSelect` and changed `orderBy` part.

```
$vtpQb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
            $vtpQb
            ->from("AppBundle:TrPlace","trplace")
            ->select($view_fectch_fields)
            ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN vwpm.tagStatusValue = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN ordCol')
            ->join('AppBundle:TrVwPlacePrivateMarkers', 'vwpm','WITH','trplace.id = vwpm.placeId')
            ->where('vwpm.userid = :userid')
            ->setParameter("userid",$userid)
            ->orderBy('ordCol', 'DESC');
```

Please note `HIDDEN` keyword in `addSelect`. It won't work without it.